# Symbology of point layer using CSS class

Tags: openlayers-2

There is nice feature [DivIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon) in Leaflet library. Is it possible to get the same function using OpenLayers? I guess I can make some workaround using [Markers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html) but not sure is this a right way. Now I'm using vector layer and have to load image for each layer separately, but in CCS case it is possible to use only one sprite for all layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers doesn't support direct CSS styling for marker and vector features. You can however directly access the marker div. In the example available here:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/markers.html

You can play with the marker style like that in JavaScript:

```
map.layers[1].markers[1].icon.imageDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
```

Your other option is to define a olAlphaImg CSS class. This is added to all marker images:

```
<style>
  .olAlphaImg {
      background-color: green;
  }
</style>
```

OpenLayers is not really designed for that, so use those tricks with caution.